# Spring security core and filterChain chainMap issue

Tags: grails, filter, spring-security

Here is my issue: I don't want to use any of spring security core filter when a user is using the API (basically, all /myapi/** request), to avoid creating a useless session. The api is based on oauth token.

So, I'm using the plugin spring-security-core for the user authentication, and I added, in my Config.groovy file,

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
'/myapi/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-securityContextPersistenceFilter,-logoutFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-securityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter,-rememberMeAuthenticationFilter,-anonymousAuthenticationFilter,-exceptionTranslationFilter',
'/**':'JOINED_FILTERS'
]
```

Basically, from what I understood, it shouldn't go throught any spring security filter for all /myapi/something, but, actually, it goes throught all the filters as it creates a session (i don't have anything for session in /myapi/something.

But, according to http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-spring-security-core/docs/manual/guide/16%20Filters.html

> So you need a /** catch-all rule at the end for URLs that do not match one of the earlier rules.

And that's why I don't understand why the request are still going throught all the filters for any /myapi/something.

Some testing I did, which may help:

It is not creating a session if I only have, in my Config.groovy:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
'/myapi/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS,-securityContextPersistenceFilter,-logoutFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-securityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter,-rememberMeAuthenticationFilter,-anonymousAuthenticationFilter,-exceptionTranslationFilter'
]
```

But it's also not creating a session for the other urls, not using any other filter, which causes the application not to work of course. This example was just to be sure that the session was not created by the /myapi/something request

If i just have:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
'/myapi/**': 'JOINED_FILTERS'
]
```

Then, it goes throught all the filters for all /myapi/something request and create a session. It doesn't use any filter for the other request. It is the excepted behavior.

Thanks a lot for your help, I have been fighting with that for some times now, and any ideas would be more than welcome!

Thanks a lot! Have a good day.

Answer (score 4):

Yup, I'm suffering from the exact same problem! Although I don't use JOINED_FILTER, I set the filter explicitly like this:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
    '/apitest/**': 'requestContextAttributesFilter,sessionPreventionFilter,objectRepositoryCreationFilter',
    '/api/**':     'requestContextAttributesFilter,sessionPreventionFilter,objectRepositoryCreationFilter,apiAuthenticationFilter',
    '/**':         'requestContextAttributesFilter,securityContextPersistenceFilter,aisAuthenticationProcessingFilter'
]
```

The last filter of the catch-all rule gets executed when I access the '/apitest/*' URL. I could not reproduce this issue when I created a simple Grails project with a few dummy filters, which only did a println, and a similar chain map. For the simple test project, the filters acted as expected. Since there doesn't seem to be a proper logging when which filter gets executed and why, it is quite difficult to pinpoint the problem. Very strange...

**UPDATE:**

I was able to reproduce this error using the Spring Security Core plugin version 1.2.7.2. However, this bug seems to be fixed with version 1.2.7.3!

See: http://jira.grails.org/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=10229&version=13100

Using version 1.2.7.3 seems to solve this issue.